# Find the position of a character in a string?

Tags: string, swift2, indexof

I need to find the position of a character in a string and to return an Int for further calculation.

```
let idx = cycleOrder.characters.indexOf(charInput)
```

This gives me the index, but how do I get this into an Int?

I tried:

```
intIdx = Int(idx)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at the `distance` functions that Index contains.

Answer (score 1):

check this code for find index of given character as Int

```
 func findIndexOfCharacter(str :String, findElement: Character) -> Int? {
  for (index, value) in Array(str.characters).enumerate() {
   if value == findElement {
    return index
  }
}
return nil
}

// Console:
 findIndexOfCharacter("hello", findElement: "e") // 1
```